# How to add 3 elements in Bootstrap's modal header?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I need my modal to have 3 elements in it:
To the left: a button
In the center: a title
To the right: the close button

When you look at my modal it seems like I achieved what I need, but in reality, my title is not centered.  Here's my code:

```css
.modal-dialog {
  max-width: 90%;
}

.modal-header {
  border: none;
}

.modal-title-filter {
  color: #2D2D2D;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Header -->
<div class="modal-header">
  <button class="btn btn-primary">Limpiar filtros</button>
  <h5 class="modal-title modal-title-filter w-100 text-center" id="exampleModalLabel">Filtros</h5>
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                      </button>
</div>
<!-- /Header -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the title is centered, centered with respect to its container h5, no to the modal-header, but if you want the title looks centered with respect to modal-header you can edit the margin-left of your title for that, try with this:

```
.modal-header .modal-title{
  margin-left: -20px;
}
```

The higher the negative value the title will be moved to the left or more centered according to your taste.

I hope i was help you. Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve something like this by setting the display of the modal header to flex, and justifying the content by the space between the items.

Note: I had to add a thing of `margin-left:0` to the close button as it has a declaration of `margin-left:auto`.

```css
.modal-dialog {
  max-width: 90%;
}

.modal-header {
  border: none;
}

.modal-title-filter {
  color: #2D2D2D;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Header -->
<div class="modal-header d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
  <button class="btn btn-primary">Limpiar filtros</button>
  <h5 class="modal-title modal-title-filter" id="exampleModalLabel">Filtros</h5>
  <button type="button" class="close" style="margin-left:0;" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                      </button>
</div>
<!-- /Header -->
```